# Lua: Prevent carriage return in binary code

Tags: insert, binary, lua, line, break

I'm trying to read a chunk from a binary file. This works fine, however, whenever there's a 0x0A in the code, Lua inserts a 0x0D and turns it into a line break, which garbles the file. How can I prevent that? I checked out several source codes for writing binary files and they use the same io.write()-function I do. I'm still new to Lua, so may be I missed something. Here's my code:

```
file=io.open(filepath,'rb')
file:seek("set")
file:seek("cur",startoffset)
filecontent=file:read(endoffset-startoffset)
io.output(test.tmp)
io.write(filecontent)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I checked out several source codes for writing binary files and they use the same io.write()-function I do.

No, they don't. They use `file:write`. There's a difference. One works on a given file handle. The other works on the "default output file", which is always opened as *text*.

The correct Lua code for what you want is this:

```
local file = assert(io.open(filepath, "rb"), "Could not open file for reading.")
local filecontent = file:read("*a")
file:close()
file = assert(io.open("temp.tmp", "wb"),  "Could not open file for writing.")
file:write(filecontent)
file:close()
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Now everything works as expected :)